# setting up a public IP address using boto3

Tags: boto3

When using boto2, I could set a cluster's IP address with the following code

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(instance['region'], aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
address = conn.get_all_addresses(filters={'public_ip': EIP_ADDRESS})[0]
conn.associate_address(instance_id=instance[u'instanceId'], allocation_id=address.allocation_id)
```

How would do that with boto3? In boto3, connect_to_region is not available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=[region], aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
address = conn.describe_addresses(filters={'public_ip': EIP_ADDRESS})[0]
conn.associate_address(instance_id=instance[u'instanceId'], allocation_id=address.allocation_id)
```

Try using this.
If you face any challenge please refer to [Amazon EC2 Boto3 Migration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/migrationec2.html) and [EC2 Boto3 Reference Guide](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)